# Need to identify molex-style connector

Tags: connector

[image]

[image]

4 Pins, 1 row.  ~1.97mm pitch (hard to measure with my calipers), 6.57mmX10.78mmX10.71mm
Says "1c 5102 MK 1 15" on it.

Comment: Have you done a through search of molex.com? Research is required BEFORE posting questions. If I can find it there or on digikey with a through search, could you also?

Comment: First time poster here so sorry about the large images.  Did try molex.com, but I'm having trouble identifying it.  Also tired digikey, but didn't find it there.  If you found it though, a link would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: There are bazillions of connectors out there. The pitch would be 2mm (that is a fairly standard pitch). Someone may be able to guess, but it is not easy. If you search on Digikey with 2mm connectors only, you may get lucky and find it. It is hard work, which is why nobody else is going to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for this connector and it seems to be the Molex KK style connector 4p. 
Check here if you haven't found it already.

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/5x-4-Way-2-54mm-0-1-PCB-Connector-Kit-Molex-KK-Style-1st-CLASS-POST-/301876749335?hash=item464941a417:g:9AwAAOSw~OVWx4NS

Comment: Check this list as well: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/listview.jsp?query=&path=cCRIMPHOUSINGS%23%230%23%232ps~~nf47%7C%7C4d696e692d4c61746368e284a2&channel=products

Comment: You guys got it! The eBay link appears to be it. Amazing!